# Beanshell Script to generate sequence of strings

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Can any one help in creating sequence of strings in multiple lines in a file using Beanshell Script

For example: Looking for output of

```
Test1,Test2,Test3
Test4,Test5,Test6
Test7,Test8,Test9
```

Tried this but giving incorrect result

```
int numSets = 1;    
for (int j = 1; j < numSets; j++) { 
    for (int i = 1; i <= numStrings; i++) {
    String str = "test" + i;
    if (i < numStrings) {
        result += str + ",";
    } else {
        result += str;
    }       
        out.write(str);

}
out.write("\n");
}
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be informed that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.

Here is an example solution in Groovy:

```
def lines = 3
def itemsPerLine = 3
def prefix = 'Test'
def counter = 1

1.upto(lines, { lineNumber ->
    1.upto(itemsPerLine, { itemNumber ->
        print(prefix + counter)
        if (itemNumber < itemsPerLine) {
            print(',')
        }
        counter++
    })
    print(System.getProperty('line.separator'))

})
```

More information: [Beanshell vs. JSR223 vs. Java For JMeter: Complete Showdown](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-jmeter)

If you want to print it to jmeter.log file or to another file you can use [StringBuilder.append()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead of `print()`

[image]